# SVG textpath issues with Firefox

Tags: html, svg

We have an element in our new website design that places hashtags on a curve generated via svg's textpath.

The development code below which was manually written works perfectly across our test browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Edge).

```
<div class="hashtags2 xp">
<svg viewbox="0 0 100 25">
<path fill="transparent" id="curve" d="M0 30 V12 Q30 17 55 12 T100 11 V30" />
<text>
<textpath text-anchor="middle" startoffset="50%" xlink:href="#curve">#PedalersKnowsBhutan &nbsp; #BicycleBhutan &nbsp; #ExperienceBhutan &nbsp; #HikeBhutan &nbsp; #DiscoverWithPedalers</textpath>
</text>
</svg>
</div>
```

But when we convert the design to a template and run it through our CMS (MODX) build process, the minified version below no longer displays the text when viewed in Firefox (Chrome and Edge still show it perfectly).

```
<div class="hashtags2 xp"><svg viewbox="0 0 100 25"><path fill="transparent" id="curve" d="M0 30 V12 Q30 17 55 12 T100 11 V30" /><text><textpath text-anchor="middle" startoffset="50%" xlink:href="#curve">#PedalersKnowsBhutan &nbsp; #BicycleBhutan &nbsp; #ExperienceBhutan &nbsp; #HikeBhutan &nbsp; #DiscoverWithPedalers</textpath></text></svg></div>
```

The only difference between the two versions is the lack of line breaks.

The CSS as requested.

```
.hashtags2 {
  z-index: 15;
  font-size: 0.15vw;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -34rem;
  left: 0;
  fill: #fff;
  width: 100%;
}

.xp { display: block; }
```

Is there a way to avoid this quirk with Firefox?

The development page, which displays correctly in Firefox, Chrome, Edge and opera:
https://pedalers.travel/sandbox/tours-v2018.7.4.4.htm

The CMS built page, which displays correctly in Chrome, Edge and Opera, but not in Firefox
https://pedalers.travel/sandbox/test-page.htm

The hashtags in question are down at the footer.

Comment: please provide more code - I suspect your CSS is missing - as I've fiddled for more than 5 minutes and can't even get your original code fragment to display fully in a page in Chrome. Even better, create a Codepen.

Comment: The CSS is the same for all six scenarios (3 browsers using development code, 3 browsers using production code) and is contained in an external css file, so not modified by the CMS.  Only one situation Firefox with production code has the display problem.

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Comment: As I can’t reproduce the problem I’m afraid I’m not going to be able to help.

Comment: CMS has a base tag, working page does not. Remove the <base> tag.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick.  But why is the base tag interfering with that particular svg?  And only on Firefox?